# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near , need some help for bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

here is the code, the CN part is working but awk...

I run function outside and it seems really clear. I just meet the bash :(

```
    windowsearch()
    {
        starting_line_number=$1
        ending_line_number=$2
        position=$3
        file_name=$4
        CN=$(head -40 "$4" | sed -n "$starting_line_number","$ending_line_number p" ) 
        awk -v CN="$CN" -F "\t" '{ print CN }' "$file_name" | sort -n -k"$position"
    
    }


windowsearch 10 20 2 $imdbdir/tsv2/title.principals.tsv
```

**desired output is like:**

should yield:

```
tt0000009    nm0085156,nm0063086,nm1309758,nm0183823
tt0000014    nm0166380,nm0525910,nm0244989
tt0000010    nm0525910
tt0000016    nm0525910
tt0000012    nm0525910,nm0525908
tt0000015    nm0721526
tt0000018    nm0804434,nm3692071
tt0000019    nm0932055
tt0000013    nm1715062,nm0525910,nm0525908
tt0000017    nm3691272,nm0804434,nm1587194,nm3692829
tt0000011    nm3692297,nm0804434
```

but my output is giving me all data in the file. So, I think my filter doesn't work.

edit: sorry for the misunderstanding, this is my first question.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Unrelated: Why assign `file_name=$4` and then use `$4` everywhere? The same goes for the other variables too.

Comment: Btw.: replace last `$CN` with `CN`.

Comment: What do you expect that `awk` command to do? It doesn't make any sense to me. Also, please fix the formatting of the command at the end; I think it should be a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) or something like that.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: When `awk` needs to do the same as the line above it, try `awk 'NR<41 { print $1 $2}' $4 `

Comment: Please provide expected input and output snippets.

Comment: I have tried to use recommendations and It has been contributed by shellcheck. It says "appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally)." for lines 3,4,5,6. I checked git-hub but I couldn't find any related solution. (and appreciated this useful tool.) @Cyrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks a description of the task and, ideally, examples of input data and desired output. It is hard to guess someone’s intentions from a completely broken script snippet. A possible wild guess might be:

```sh
windowsearch() {
  awk "NR > ${2} {exit}
       NR >= ${1}" < "$4" | sort -k "$3"
}
```

The `awk` code `exit`s after it exceeds the upper limit on line numbers and prints entire lines after it reaches the lower limit. (`NR` is the current line number.) The output from `awk` (which is the interval of lines between the lower and upper limit) gets `sort`ed (which `awk` itself can do as well, but using `sort` was shorter in this case).

Example (sort `/etc/fstab` lines 9 through 13 by mount point (field 2)):

```sh
windowsearch 9 13 2 /etc/fstab
```

Comment: It has worked, thank you but I had to remove the CN part. Could you please explain a bit this code?

Comment: Of course, the `CN` part didn’t make much sense anyway. I’ll add a short explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your intention

you want to sort a range of lines from a file based on a given column.

```
$ awk -v start=10 -v end=20 'start<=NR && NR<=end' | sort -n k2
```

just parametrize input values in your script